# iOS default start-url for Progressive web app

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

i am trying to build a progressive web app, my starting page url is  "/". I mentioned it in the manifest.json "start_url": "/" but didnt work for ios.
I guess there's a meta tag for ios for default-start-url like

```
<meta name="aplle-mobile-web-app-title" content="AB Coders">
```

for title.
Is there any?

Comment: Try using `msapplication-starturl`, I found this in github : [iOS Add to Homescreen => simulate web app manifest](https://gist.github.com/PaulKinlan/d66f777f5bde04926f29fc5c7ff345e7). I think this is the equivalent of `"start_url": "/"` for android.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific meta tag for that https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

You can try to configure your manifest with "start_url": "../name_of_your_index_file"